# Adding space between multiple c macro paster

Tags: c

I have a C macro like this

```
#define ADD_API(NAME) func_##NAME ##NAME;
typedef struct
{
    ADD_API("Whatever")
} xxx;
```

I expect it to be

```
typedef struct
{
    func_Whatever Whatever;
}
```

But it becomes

```
typedef struct
{
     func_WhateverWhatever;
}
```

The space are removed, what should I use now?

Comment: Remove the second `##`

Comment: @Dani Interesting ... Why is the second NAME parsed without ##?

Comment: Please post the actual code. This code results in `func_"Whatever""Whatever"`.

Comment: @Lundin this is the actual code on VS 2019

Comment: Maybe you're using a different compiler?

Comment: Not even VS is bad enough to compile this. Copy paste the actual code. https://godbolt.org/z/jARDZM

Comment: Try `#define ADD_API(NAME) func_##NAME  #NAME;`

Comment: @ManthanTilva No don't try that because it's clearly wrong. `#` turns a pre-processor token into a string.

Comment: @Lundin, yup you right. My mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C pre-processor uses whitespace as the way to distinguish between pre-processor tokens. So just as in any C code, the amount of spaces in macros doesn't matter. When you use the pre-processor token concatenator `##` you merge two tokens together though, regardless of how much whitespace there is between them. And this is not what you want to do.

Assuming that you actually use the macro as `ADD_API(Whatever);` (with semicolon) and not as a string literal, then the correct macro should be

```
#define ADD_API(NAME) func_##NAME NAME
```

with no semicolon in the end.

This expands `ADD_API(Whatever);` into `func_Whatever Whatever;`

Comment: @Cœur I don't remember but it is obviously a tag not related to programming.